# How to create linux sdcard image?

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded, sd-card, disk-image

I want to create a image file that contains two partitions:

1. 100MB FAT Boot partition that contains my kernel zImage and dtb(device tree blob) files.
2. 900MB EXT4 Rootfs partition that contains my root file system.

Then I want to be able to flash that image file to any sdcard to boot may linux board.

How can I do this and what tools I need? (I prefer cli based tools rather than GUI)

Note: **I have my kernel zImage and DTB and rootfs already and I need to make an sdcard bootable image of all of them to easily burn it on any sdcard. But for now I don't have an sdcard. I'll buy my sdcards later. first I want to have the image ready and when I buy them I'll flash the image on all of them swiftly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an easy task! Just follow these 15 steps.

steps:

1. Allocate a file space with `fallocate -l 500M sd.img`.
2. Use **fdisk**(dos partition table) or **gdisk**(gpt(guided partition table)) to create partition table `sudo fdisk sd.img`.
3. After opening fdisk, create a partition by pressing `n` and then press `p` to create a primary partition and then just press enter to leave everything by default, except the "Last sector" option. enter `+100M` to create a 100MB partition.
4. Redo the third step to create the second partition.
5. Enter `w` to save and exit.
6. Create loop device of your image using `sudo kpartx -av sd.img`.
7. Format the partitions `sudo mkfs.fat /dev/mapper/loop0p1` and `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p2`.
8. Create a mounting points `sudo mkdir /mnt/temp_part1/` & `sudo mkdir /mnt/temp_part2/`.
9. Mount the partitions `sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/temp_part1/`  and `sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/temp_part2/` .
10. copy your content into the mounting points.
11. sync `sudo sync`.
12. Unmount them `sudo umount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/temp_part1/` and `sudo umount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/temp_part2/`
13. Delete loop devices `sudo kpartx -d sd.img`
14. Flash your image on your sdcard using any flasher software on any OS. I use [BalenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).
15. Enjoy your SD Card!